# Angular2. Provider/Service function is undefined when called form component

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I'm working on a Ionic 2 project.

This is the **provider**/**service** in which I make a request to my local API...

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceTest {
  // data: any = null;
  public data;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.data = null;
  }

  retrieveData(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/people')
    .subscribe(res => {
      return this.data = res.text();
      // console.log(this.data);
    })
  }

  getData(){
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

And the export class of the component : which returns undefined in the console

```
export class Page1 {
  constructor(public data:ServiceTest) {
    this.data = data;
    console.log(this.data.retrieveData());
    console.log(this.data.getData());
  }
}
```

The thing is that when I do a console.log(this.data.text()) from the service, everything is outputted just fine in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data are loaded asynchronously. So I would update your code this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceTest {
  (...)

  retrieveData(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/people')
      .map(res => res.text())
      .do(data => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }
```

and in your component:

```
export class Page1 {
  constructor(public data:ServiceTest) {
    this.data.retrieveData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.data.getData());
    });
  }
}
```

Here are some explanations regarding the operators used above:

- **`map` operator**: aims to transform the value of the element in the data flow to something else. See this link: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md
- **`do` operator**: triggers an action imperatively without changing the dataflow. See this link: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md.

The `subscribe` method is used to receive the result / events or errors / completion on a data flow.

Comment: What does the `.do` and `.map` and `.subscribe` http callbacks do?
Can you explain please?

Comment: Yes sure! I added some details in my answer. If you want to know more about reactive programming / observables, I would recommend the following tutorial: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754.

Comment: thank you, reactive programming is the next thing I shall learn

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it's used a lot in Angular2 ;-)